# JQuery change() dynamically loaded event issue

Tags: jquery, onchange

I'm trying to attach an `.change()` event to a drop down select field using JQuery. The code is as follows:

```
<div id="productVariants" class="group">
    <label for="product-option">Rental Options :</label>
    <select name="id" id="productSelect" style="visibility:hidden;width:400px;">
        <option disabled="disabled">3 Day Rental ($5.68 per day) ($17.05) - SOLD OUT</option>
        <option value="801110989">7 Day Rental ($4.41 per day) ($30.85)</option>
        <option value="894325197">10 Day Rental ($3.71 per day) ($37.12)</option>
        <option value="894454745">14 Day Rental ($3.32 per day) ($46.44)</option>
    </select>
</div><!-- productVariants -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select")
      .change(function () {
          var str = "";
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
              alert('changed');
          });
      })
      .change();
</script>
```

The event only seems to fire once when the page loads and not when I change the selected item. Does anyone know how to get this event to fire each time the select box is changed?

Comment: It works fine for me. How are you changing the selected item when the menu is invisible? I had to remove `visibility: hidden` before I could run your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move that `JS` block to inside the `[$(document).ready()][1]` event. This will ensure the page (DOM) is ready and has registered that event with your `<select>` control. This way it will fire every time a selection has changed.

I also recommend using the selector of the actual control `$("#productSelect")`) as opposed to the code you have which will fire that event for *every* select control. This might be the logic you deisre but odds are it is control specific so you can capture selection data to make subsequent `AJAX` calls or whatever else needed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#productSelect").change(function () {
            //Populate variable with the 'option value'      
            var selectValue = $(this).val();
            alert('select changed value selected is: ' + selectValue);

        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#productSelect").change(function () {
    var str = "";
    // To fetch value of selected option
    str = $(this).val();

    alert('changed');

});
```

I have removed some unnecessary code.